# Do i need extensive ui experience to android?

Tags: android, user-interface, adt, eclipse-adt

I'm starting to get into the android world but there is a question in my mind that leaves me in doubt. We all know that for an application to be attractive, it must provide a good ui experience for the user. And although I have extensive front-end experience in developing enterprise web applications, I don't have a clue about graphic design. Do I really need to possess graphical knowledge to create visually-attractive applications? Java is my homeland and I don't have a problem with any aspect of the actual programming. That is the only thing that makes me think. I'd very much like to get your opinions on the matter and appreciate if you could point me out some directions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: IF you want it to look good, then yes UI experience will help.  This goes for anything written for any platform.  Can you get something usable written without it?  Yes, and that also goes for every platform ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While being a UI/UX/Photoshop expert is not required, it definitely helps. You should first review the design guidelines set by Google. It is quite extensive and covers how your app should look and behave:

http://developer.android.com/design/index.html

In Android, it is relatively easy to develop apps that keep that stock look, by using the stock themes and default UI elements. And there are plenty of [tools](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html) out there that will give you the basic, stock themed looks for icons and UI elements. However, if you want a custom looking app with a unique look and feel, you will need to be able to create your own UI resources.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you do not *need* it, but it certainly helps. A lot of android users like the Holo UI so stick with that. All the icons are readily available and free to use. Just make sure that you do not misuse any of the icons (say, using a trashcan for save).